# How to tell which database tables belongs to which multisite site

Tags: multisite, database

I have a local multisite installation I use for development with a relatively large number of sites set up. Every site has its own numbered database tables (i.e. `wp_n_links`, `wp_n_options`, `wp_n_postmeta` etc.)

Every time I need to look at a database table in phpMyAdmin I have to look through all the `wp_n_options` tables to find the tables for the site I need and with a lot of sites this can get a bit tedious!

Is there a better way to find out which tables belong to which site?

Comment: How are you looking at database tables, in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that, yes in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: are you looking for a way to find the blog_id for a given site (like tsipilai  shows) or are you looking for a way to display all tables related to a given table prefix (my understanding)?

Comment: Well, now i realise I'm looking for the blog_id for a given site. I didn't realise the number in the table name corresponded to the blog_id.. I feel a bit stupid now.

Comment: no problem, please don't feel that. I just thought you're looking for some general search tools within PHPMyAdmin ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number you refer to is the blog/site ID, so you have multiple methods of finding out which site it is:

- Look in the sites table, the number should match the ID, providing you with a URL and title
- Go to example.com/wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=*insert-number-here* and you'll be shown the network admin UI for that site
- Consider a plugin or custom column in the sites area of the network admin that displays the blog ID

Answer (score 8):

Look the wp_blogs table, theres "blog_id" and "path" to identify that. Does it help?

Comment: That actually does help! I didn't realise the blog_id corresponded to the numbers in the table names.

Comment: +1, but the one thing to be aware of is that AFAIK the domain mapping plugins use their own setting area so if you use them this might not give you the mapped domain.